# Chaining Retrofit calls using RxJava

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I'm trying to get myself into RxJava so I read some posts about it. I think I understood how it works but I would like to submit you a theorical code to ensure my good understanding of the library.

Let's imagine I have an API enabling to retrieve a list of produceur and for each of them the artists they produce, their albums and their songs.
My model would be the following

```
public class Produceur {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String pictureUrl;
}

public class Artist {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String lastname;
    private String sceneName;
    private String pictureUrl;
}

public class Album {
    private Integer id;
    private int year;
    private String name;
    private String style;
    private String pictureUrl;
    private Integer artistId;
}

public class Song {
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    private int duration;
    private String pictureUrl;
    private Integer albumId;
}
```

With my Retrofist services

```
@GET("myUrl/produceurs")
Observable<List<ProduceurResponse>> getProduceurs();

@GET("myUrl/produceurs/{produceurId}")
Observable<List<ArtisteResponse>> getArtistForProduceur(@Path("produceurId") Integer produceurId);

@GET("myUrl/picture/{id}")
Observable<ResponseBody> getPicture(@Path("id") Integer id);
```

And the response objects

```
public class ProduceurResponse {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String pictureUrl;
}

public class ArtisteResponse {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String lastname;
    private String sceneName;
    private String pictureUrl;
    private List<AlbumResponse> albums;
}

public class AlbumResponse {
    private Integer id;
    private int year;
    private String name;
    private String style;
    private String pictureUrl;
    private Integer artistId;
    private List<SongResponse> songs;
}

public class SongResponse {
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    private int duration;
    private String pictureUrl;
    private Integer albumId;
}
```

I would like to retrieve all the produceur and for each the artists and save all the images in the local memory in the same sequence.
I thought about the following code where for each produceur we will retrieve the artists, their albums and song and insert them into our base.
And once we've finished retrieveing the produceurs and artists we can download images (we stored in a list every id with a picture).

```
getProduceurs().flatMap(produceurs -> Observable.from(produceurs))
               .doOnNext(produceur -> insertProduceurInBase(produceur))
               .subscribe(produceur -> Observable.from(getArtistForProduceur(produceur.getId())
                                                 .flatMap(artists -> Observable.from(artists))
                                                 .doOnNext(artist -> insertArtistInBase(artist)))
                                                 .subscribe(),

                          e -> showError(e),

                          () -> Observable.from(listOfIdsToDownload)
                                          .doOnNext(id -> getPicture(id))
                                          .subscribe(response -> createImage(response),

                                          e -> showError(e),

                                          () -> isFinished()
                                          )
                         );
```

Would this code work (I think so but I'm not sure) ? Is this the best way to do it ?

Now, what if my getProduceurs service return me a list of ProduceurResponse containing produceur artists ids and I got a service to retrieve the artist profil and another one to retrieve its albums.

```
public class ProduceurResponse {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String pictureUrl;
    List<Integer> artistsIds;
}

public class ArtisteProfileResponse {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String lastname;
    private String sceneName;
    private String pictureUrl;
}

@GET("myUrl/artist/{artistId}")
Observable<List<ArtisteProfileResponse>> getArtistProfile(@Path("artistId") Integer artistId);

@GET("myUrl/artist/{artistId}/detail")
Observable<List<AlbumResponse>> getArtistAlbums(@Path("artistId") Integer artistId);
```

I could to use the .zip to make the getArtistProfile() and getArtistAlbums() call simultaneous with something like

```
getProduceurs().flatMap(produceurs -> Observable.from(produceurs))
               .doOnNext(produceur -> insertProduceurInBase(produceur))
               .subscribe(produceur -> Observable.from(produceur.getArtistIds())
                                                 .zip(
                                                        getArtistProfile(),
                                                        getArtistAlbums(),
                                                        (artistProfil, albumList) -> insertArtistInBase()
                                                 )
                                                 .subscribe(),

                          e -> showError(e),

                          () -> Observable.from(listOfIdsToDownload)
                                          .doOnNext(id -> getPicture(id))
                                          .subscribe(response -> createImage(response),

                                          e -> showError(e),

                                          () -> isFinished()
                                          )
                         );
```

But I'm really not sure I'm using the zip the right way. Is zip well used in this piece of code ? Would this work ? Is this the best way to do it ?

EDIT

So I tried to implement something similar to my original idea with the google books api.

I've got a Retrofit interface

```
public interface IBookService {
    @GET("volumes?q=robot+subject:fiction")
    Observable<BookSearchResult> getFictionAuthors(@Query("category") String key);
    @GET("volumes")
    Observable<BookSearchResult> getBooksForAuthor(@Query("q") String author, @Query("category") String key);
}
```

With

```
public class BookSearchResult {
    public List<BookResult>  items;
}

public class BookResult {
    public String id;
    public String selfLink;
    public VolumeInfoResult volumeInfo;
    public SaleInfoResult saleInfo;
}
```

And I try to retrieve the books of fiction with a the string robot (getFictionAuthors) with return me a BookSearchResult containing a list of BookResult. For each of the book results I retrieve all the books of the author with getBooksForAuthor. My code is below

```
Observable<BookResult> observable = mWebService.getFictionAuthors(API_KEY)
                .flatMap(new Func1<BookSearchResult, Observable<BookResult>>() {

                    // Parse the result and build a CurrentWeather object.
                    @Override
                    public Observable<BookResult> call(final BookSearchResult data) {
                        return Observable.from(data.items);
                    }
                })
                .concatMap(new Func1<BookResult, Observable<BookSearchResult>>() {

                    // Parse the result and build a CurrentWeather object.
                    @Override
                    public Observable<BookSearchResult> call(final BookResult data) {
                        return mWebService.getBooksForAuthor("=inauthor:" + data.volumeInfo.authors.get(0), API_KEY);
                    }
                })
                .flatMapIterable(new Func1<BookSearchResult, List<BookResult>>() {

                    // Parse the result and build a CurrentWeather object.
                    @Override
                    public List<BookResult> call(final BookSearchResult data) {
                        return data.items;
                    }
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<BookResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(final BookResult book) {
                        Log.e("Book","Book is " + book.volumeInfo.title + " written by " + book.volumeInfo.authors.get(0));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        Log.e("Book","Book list completed");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(final Throwable error) {
                        Log.e("Book","Book list error");
                    }
                }
```

This code is working but there is something weird that I don't understand. In my logs I have at first the return from the getBooksForAuthor request for the first author and then the log from each book of that author. After that I've got the result of the request for the second author and part of the log from his books. Follow the results of the request of the other authors and then the end of the list of books for the second author and the list of books for all the other authors.

To illustrate it, my logs looks like

```
- > Return from request for Author 1
- > Book 1 from author 1
...
- > Book 10 from author 1
- > Return from request for Author 2
- > Book 1 from author 2
...
- > Book 5 from author 2
- > Return from request for Author 3
- > Return from request for Author 4
...
- > Return from request for Author 10
- > Book 6 from author 2
..
- > Book 10 from author 2
- > Book 1 from author 3
..
- > Book 10 from author 3
...
- > Book 1 from author 10
..
- > Book 10 from author 10
```

When I expected

```
- > Return from request for Author 1
- > Book 1 from author 1
...
- > Book 10 from author 1
- > Return from request for Author 2
- > Book 1 from author 2
...
- > Book 10 from author 2
...
- > Return from request for Author 10
- > Book 1 from author 10
...
- > Book 10 from author 10
```

Does someone have an explanation or understand what I'm missing ?

Comment: what exactly you want, like to want to save the images in sequences right?

Comment: I would like to retrieve all my data and save my images in the same sequence. What I have in mind is that I log in, my app retrieve all the data I need and then I can use the app.

Comment: rxjava has this operators : merge() - which gets data in sequence that it receives from api. buffer() : this operator creates buffer so that there is no load. you can try this

Comment: you have to create a BaseActivity to do all Api calls so that you can use them

Comment: From what I understood of merge, its purpose is to combine Observables into a single Observable. So it might replace the zip but I don't figure out what else I could do with it. Did I misunderstood the merge function ?

Comment: nope that was right

Comment: what you mean by what can i do more? can you be specific?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear in my post. What I would like to do is to call getProduceurs() which give me a list of produceurs. With this list i will call getArtistForProduceur() for each produceur I have. So I need to have the result of getProduceurs() to make my multiple getArtistForProduceur() calls.

Comment: If the purpose of your answer was pointing out that merge could replace zip I just didn't understood that it was the point of your comment and thank you for pointing this out :)

Comment: I am talking in general, if you want to make multiple api calls do it in baseActivity which is the mainActivity... and the use this all data elsewhere

Comment: I will keep that in mind, thank you. Any other advice for the code I wrote ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid nested subscription (check out the flatmap operator). It's offen an indicator of a code smell.
To avoid nested subscription, you can use the operator `flatMap` (do not garanti resulting events order) or `concatMap` (garanti resulting events order).

I notice too that you're using another `Observable` in the completed callback : you can `concat` observables in this case.

So the rework of your code using this sort of operators :

```
 getProduceurs().flatMap(produceurs -> Observable.from(produceurs))
                .doOnNext(produceur -> insertProduceurInBase(produceur))
                // call getArtistForProduceur and emit results in order
                .concatMap(produceur -> getArtistForProduceur(produceur.getId()))
                // emits items of the list
                .flatMapIterable(artists -> artists)
                .doOnNext(artist -> insertArtistInBase(artist)))
                // don't care about elements. But will wait for the completion of the previous observable
                .ignoreElements()
                // perform jobs after the previous observable complete
                .concatWith(Observable.from(listOfIdsToDownload)
                                      .doOnNext(id -> getPicture(id))
                                      .doOnNext(response -> createImage(response)))
                // show an error if an error occur in the downstream
                .doOnError(e -> showError(e))
                // call isFinished when everything is finished.
                .doOnCompleted(() -> isFinished())
                .subscribe()
```

Comment: Thank very much, that look much nicer, I didn't know about concatMap. I still have a question : is flatMapIterable(artists -> artists) the same as flatMap(artists -> Observable.from(artists)) ?

Comment: yes it is. see : http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#flatMapIterable(rx.functions.Func1)

Comment: Thank for your help !

Comment: I implemented something similar to what you answered but I don't fully understand what is happening. When I use ignoreElements() and then flatMap or concatMap, nothing happen (I mean, my concatMap or flatMap code is not executed), but when using concatWith it's working. I don't understand why. Could you explain it ?

Comment: `ignoreElements` ... ignore elements. So you won't be notified from new element. That's why flatMap / concatMap is never notified from new elements. (and don't confuse concatMap with concatWith.)

Comment: Well I think I figured it out. Since the ignoreElements() skip all the emitted items, flatMap and concatMap have nothing to be fed with, whereas concatWith is fed with his own observable. Thank for your answer.